# Google Speech Transcription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api, transcription

If the Google Speech API transcribes audio at near real time, and my latency to the actual server is only 50ms, why do I receive my final streaming transcription result after 1.6s? Shouldn’t I receive it in only a couple hundred milliseconds?

Comment: Well, that is pretty generic. Can you be more specific? How are you calling the service, is your account free?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to speed up google cloud speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364955/how-to-speed-up-google-cloud-speech)

Comment: You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51359674/9908267). Apart from the transcription speed itself, authentication takes time every time a call is made to the API.

Comment: Using the c# client library and yes the account is free

Comment: Is it possible to avoid authenticating for each request?

Comment: You can use [API Keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) for authentication. Bear in mind with using the API Keys you lose the ability to track from whom the requests are being made and it might be easier for others to discover the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [API Keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) for authentication. Bear in mind with using the API Keys you lose the ability to track from whom the requests are being made and it might be easier for others to discover the key.

Also, you might want to check this other question: [how to speed up google cloud speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364955/how-to-speed-up-google-cloud-speech)